# Executing "who am i" in tmux doesn't show result

Tags: tmux

when I am in a tmux session and execute "who am i" I don't get anything back. It seems tmux somehow breaks "who am i". Is there a fix for that?

Edit to clarify what is happening:
I have a script that is executed as root user and I want to be able to log who executes it.

If someone

1. Logs in with their user using ssh
2. Does an `su -`
3. Executes the script then `who am i` returns the login user and IP of the clent

I noticed if someone uses tmux in between then this doesn't work anymore

1. Log in with their user using ssh
2. tmux (in case they get disconnected)
3. `su -`
4. `who am i` returns nothing. `whoami` and `$USER` show root

Comment: Does `who` or `whoami` give back something?

Comment: `who` gives back a list of all the users logged in, including mine. `whoami` seems to give my user.

For `who` I see pts/1 as my terminal. However a `ps` shows that my bash is running under pts/8. pts/8 doesn't show up in `who`

Comment: The problem with `whoami` is that it shows my current user, not my login user like `who am i` would.

Comment: I updated my ask with the exact steps

Comment: If it worked (e.g. you fixed it thanks to my answer or whatever) and the user did `su -` *before* `tmux`, then `who am i` would return `root`. A better way may be to let users `sudo your_script` and just examine `/var/log/auth.log` (or similar log) or rely on `$SUDO_USER` (within the script). Note if users can do `su -` then they can purposely mislead you in many ways.

Answer (score 5):

It seems [tmux has to be built with `--enable-utempter`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1260#issuecomment-366707873) to update `utmp(5)`. Then a proper binary must be available.

In your case `who am i` inside tmux finds no entry associated with stdin (which in tmux is like `pts/1` or so; pseudo terminal slave). Possibilities:

- Your `tmux` was built without `--enable-utempter` and therefore did not try to update `utmp` (to register the pseudo terminal slave there) when the pane was created.
- Or there is no `utempter` executable tmux can use. In my Debian 9 it's

  ```
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/utempter/utempter
  ```

  (just in case: permissions `rwxr-sr-x`, ownership `root:utmp`).

To fix, make sure you have `utempter`. In Debian 9 it's in the `libutempter0` package. If the file is there and the problem persists then most likely you need to rebuild tmux, this time with `--enable-utempter`.

Comment: Thank you for this is a terrific explanation!
--enable-utempter should be used as part of the configure command. utempter.h file should be located where the compiler can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `echo $USER`. If that fails, here is something that may work:

```
cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | grep $UID
```

Comment: `$USER` and `$UID` have the info of the current user, not the login user like `who am i` would get me

Comment: What is it that you are asking for exactly? The commands `whoami` and `echo $USER` have never differed in output for me.

Comment: If you `sudo` onto another user ID, in theory, you won't get the login ID, but the sudo ID for `whoami`

Comment: My script is usually executed under root. I want to know who executes it. `who am i` gives me the login user as well as the IP from where the login came from. When you do a `su -` then your `$USER` and `$UID` reflect root. Same with `whomai`. I basically noticed if someone uses tmux then `who am i` doesn't work anymore as it returns nothing. `whoami`, `$USER` and `$UID` don't give me the same information as `who am i` would have.